# Android SIP or webRTC only for voip/audio calls?

Tags: android, sip, webrtc

I am fairly new in this things, my basic question is in here:

What is the best and easy way to create an audio call on web with two phones in android? Is it enough if I only use the built in Sip codes in android, or I have to use webRTC or other 3rd party libraries?

**more: I have to record the calls in 3gpp or mpeg4 file format.**

Thanks,
Leslie

Comment: If you use SIP, you have to have a SIP server for registration. If you use WebRTC, you have to use a signalling server for session startup. Choose your poison.

Comment: ok, any way to record the calls with the builtin android Sip library?

Comment: I am sure there is depending on what RTP stack you are using.

Answer (score -1):

For Audio call sip code is enough, there is no need for webrtc. 
You can also go for csipsimple.